# Serial communication with a modem, tcdrain/tcflush

Tags: c++, unix, serial-port, blocking, termios

I am trying to create a reliable serial communication with a UHF modem. Here is the steps I do:

To send a command to the modem:

```
 1. tcflush(fd, TCIOFLUSH)
 2. readEmpty(fd) -> custom function that reads from fd in a while loop until no characters left, so that fd is empty before reading
 3. write(fd,buf,len) -> send the command to the uhf modem
 4. tcdrain(fd) -> wait for the command to reach the modem
```

Then, for reading the reply, I enter a loop where:

```
 1. Wait on a select() statement with a relatively big initial timeout
 2. read(fd)
 3. Update timeout value to smaller one, since I already started reading some data, and go back to select(), waiting for more possible data
```

My questions are:

1. Is the use of `tcdrain()` and `tcflush()` correct like this? Is there any alternative for these?
2. I read that `tcdrain()` is blocking and can happen that it never returns. Is there a way to create a timeout mechanism for `tcdrain`, or use some other alternative that does not have this issue?

Comment: The usage of `tcdrain` and `tcflush` appears to be correct, but something very critical appears to have been overlooked: checking what `write()` returns, and handling the resulting logic correctly.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to create a reliable serial communication ...

That's a worthy goal.

> 1. Is the use of tcdrain() and tcflush() correct like this?

Not really.

**tcdrain()** typically only needs to be used to explicitly synchronize with the hardware, for example flip a control line after the stop bit has been transmitted. Otherwise the detection of this completion event can often be substituted with a  higher-level event such as the arrival of a response.

Your notation of "*wait for the command to reach the modem*" for **tcdrain()** is optimistic. The **tcdrain()** syscall only waits for the local peripheral to transmit the data. What happens next is completely unknown. The arrival of this data at the destination is never assured with this one syscall. The cable may be unplugged from your system, and the data/message (e.g. a command) would never reach its intended destination (e.g. the modem).

---

IMO **tcflush()** typically only needs to be used after a change in line settings (e.g. baudrate, frame size, parity) or as a last resort during cleanup after an error situation.
Your userspace program is executing in a multitasking environment, and normally is never in synchronization with the arrival of data from the serial link as well as the layers of terminal processing and buffering (e.g. study [Linux serial drivers](https://www.linux.it/%7Erubini/docs/serial/serial.html)). Unless you think you have full control of when serial messages can arrive (e.g. on the master side of a master-slave connection), I can imagine a scenario where a misbehaving slave unit sends a message at an inopportune time to thwart a simple scheme to only read "clean" messages.
IOW instead of using **tcfliush()** to (futilely) try to remove "unwanted" bytes from being read, the read processing needs to be robust to handle more than just perfectly received, intact, and timely responses.

> Is there any alternative for these?

For your intended purpose of "*a reliable serial communication*", yes.
You don't need to use **tcdrain()**. A response from the modem is confirmation that the request was successfully transmitted and received.
You don't need to use **tcflush()**. Instead of unconditionally discarding data, the processing of received data needs to be robust and capable of detecting malformed or unexpected responses.

Your scheme of intentionally discarding data sent by the modem without any consideration does not seem to meet your goal of "*reliable serial communication*". Since the modem sent this data, could this data have some value or meaning that at least deserves inspection? The scheme seems more like "let's keep the program simple".

> 2. I read that tcdrain() is blocking and can happen that it never returns. Is there a way to create a timeout mechanism for tcdrain, or use some other alternative that does not have this issue?

You can probably avoid this issue by simply only using **tcdrain()** when actually necessary. Your example of **tcdrain()** is not necessary IMO.

An extended block in **tcdrain()** would probably occur when (a) there's a significant hardware failure (that's really not worth recovering from), or (b) flow-control (i.e. HW or SW handshake) is active and blocking the transmission.

Comment: _You don't need to use tcdrain(). A response from the modem is confirmation that the request was successfully transmitted and received._
-> The problem with the modem I'm using is that it does not provide a specific ACK at the end of its reply. So I would have to rely on the format of the expected response, which is possible to change with newer firmware or a newer model.

Comment: The format of the modem's response or your ability to parse such a response is not relevant to the utility of **tcdrain()**. One more time: **tcdrain()** does not "*wait for the command to reach the modem*:,